# What is the cause behind the revelation of verse in regards to Uzair (9:30)?

Tags: tafseer, jews, judaism, quranic-events

Allah Said:

> [Quran 9:30](https://quran.com/9/30)
>
> وَقَالَتِ الْيَهُودُ عُزَيْرٌ ابْنُ اللَّهِ
>
> and the Jews said, "Uzair/Ezra is the son of Allah "

I am wondering, what was the cause of this verse to come down?

Comment: your question made me search a Tafseer book in which I found a Hadeeth from Ahlul Bayt --peace be upon them-- narrating a debate between the holy prophet --peace be upon him and his household-- and some scholars of Jews, Christians and etc. Alas the Hadeeth (in Arabic) is too long for me to be able translate it but I put the related part of the Arabic text in the chat room [http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8885598#8885598 ], maybe you would like to read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is narrated in Attabari 16620 that a group of Jews came to the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) and they said:

> Why would we follow you and you have left our Qibla and do not believe that Uzair/Ezra is the son of God.
>
> كيف نتبعك وقد تركت قبلتنا ، وأنت لا تزعم أن عزيرا ابن الله؟

So that Ayah came down in regards to what they said: "Uzair the son of God".

Sources: Mawsu'ati Saheehul Masboor Mina Attafseeril Ma'thoor (موسوعة الصحيح المسبور من التفسير بالمأثور المجلد الثاني صفحة 442-443)

Comment: Although it helps direct me most of the time, I don't think ahlalhadith.com should not be recognized as valid reference site, it's a forum full of mistakes and spam-style posts.

Comment: @TamerShlash true, but this post I have cited has citations and I have also checked some of them.  Like I have personally checked the book, so even if ahlalhadith.com is a bad citation, the citation to the book is a strong one.

Comment: @TamerShlash I just removed it, for I do not know what happened but I couldn't see it anymore perhaps it was removed or something.

Comment: The entire forum content is not available, at least not for a visitor.

Answer (score 2):

Tafsirs state that this was revealed in response to a specific group of the Jews who said this to the Prophet Muhammad(p.b.u.h) and was not a common belief, nor does it remain a canonical belief in Judaism.

From [Tafsir Al Qurtubi](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=5&tSoraNo=9&tAyahNo=30&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=1):

> قوله تعالىٰ: { وَقَالَتِ ٱلْيَهُودُ } هذا لفظ خرج على العموم ومعناه
> الخصوص؛ لأن ليس كل اليهود قالوا ذلك. وهذا مثلُ قوله تعالىٰ: {
> ٱلَّذِينَ قَالَ لَهُمُ ٱلنَّاسُ } [آل عمران: 173] ولم يقل ذلك كل
> الناس. وقيل: إن قائل ما حكي عن اليهود سلاّم بن مِشْكم ونعمان ابن أبي
> أوْفِى وشاس بن قيس ومالك بن الصّيف؛ قالوه للنبيّ صلى الله عليه وسلم.
> قال النقاش: لم يبق يهودي يقولها، بل انقرضوا؛
>
> Allah says: "And the Jews say". The word is general but its meaning
> is specific, because not all the Jews said this. And this is
> similar to the saying of Allah in [3:173](https://quran.com/3/173?translations=20) الَّذِينَ قَالَ لَهُمُ النَّاسُ إِنَّ النَّاسَ   [ where An-Nas (the people) is used to refer to a group of hypocrites] when
> not all of the people said that.
>
> It has been said that the Jews who said this includeed  Salaam ibn Mashkam, Nu‘maan ibn Awfa, Shaas ibn Qays, and Maalik ibn as-Sayf. They
> said this to the Prophet Muhammad(p.b.u.h).
>
> Al-Naqash said: No Jew remains who says this, but all of them have been
> destroyed.

From [Tafsir Al Jassas](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=780&bk_no=212&flag=1)

> إنه أراد فرقة من اليهود قالت ذلك ؛ والدليل على ذلك أن اليهود قد سمعت
> ذلك في عهد النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فلم تنكره ، وهو كقول القائل :
> الخوارج ترى الاستعراض وقتل الأطفال ، والمراد فرقة منهم لا جميعهم ؛
> وكقولك : جاءني بنو تميم ، والمراد بعضهم . قال ابن عباس : { قال ذلك
> جماعة من اليهود جاءوا إلى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فقالوا ذلك ، وهم
> سلام بن مشكم ، ونعمان بن أوفى ، وشاس بن قيس ، ومالك بن الصيف ، فأنزل
> الله تعالى هذه الآية } ، وليس في اليهود من يقول ذلك الآن فيما نعلم ،
> وإنما كانت فرقة منهم قالت ذلك فانقرضت
>
> This means a group among the Jews. The evidence of truth of this verse
> is that when the Jews in the time of the Prophet Muhammad(p.b.u.h)
> heard this they didn't object to it.
>
> The example of this is that if a person says "The Khawarij commit
> massacres and consider it valid to kill children" then this will mean
> that a group of the Khawarij and not all of them.
> Similarly when one says "Banu Tamim came to me" then this does not
> mean the whole tribe but some people from them.
>
> Ibn Abbas has narrated that this was said by one group from the Jews.
> They came to the Prophet and said this to him. The group included
> Salaam ibn Mashkam, Nu‘maan ibn Awfa, Shaas ibn Qays, and Maalik ibn as-Sayf. On this, Allah revealed the verse.
>
> As far as we know, now no Jew holds this view, a sect among them said
> this and it has now been erased.

Comment: +1 for adding another view , I read this before too, I think i also heard another view that it only was one Jew that said that too. Also the quote about the wording "alladina qala lahomo annaso..." is a good example, whereas naas doesn't necessary mean all people. Same conclusions could be used in the hadith "omirto an o9atila an-naas hata yashadho..."

Answer (score 0):

(uzair is the Ezra the scribe in Judaism)

and the Targum reads, “by the hand of my angel, whose name is called Ezra the scribe.

https://www.internationalstandardbible.com/M/malachi.html

The Targum of Jonathan ben-Uzziel, on the words “by the hand of Malachi” (1:1), gives the gloss “whose name is called Ezra the scribe.” With equal probability Malachi has been identified with Mordecai, Nehemiah, and Zerubbabel. The Sept., as above noted renders “by Malachi” (Mal 1:1), “by the hand of his angel;” and this translation appears to have given rise to the idea that Malachi, as well as Haggai and John the Baptist, was an angel in human shape (comp. Mal 3:1;

https://www.biblicalcyclopedia.com/M/malachi.html

In Judaism, angels call him the sons of God

https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/angels-and-angelology-2